# Is there a way to describe a field in typedoc?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, summary, typedoc

The code is:

```
/**
* Class description
*/

export class SomeClass {
  /**
   * The field description
   */
  message: string;
}
```

I'm checking it on the [TSDoc playground](https://tsdoc.org/play#) and see, that there is the summary for class, but there is no summary for its field

Is there a way to describe a field in typedoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TSDoc playground is extremely limited - it will only parse and display the first doc comment it finds. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/tsdoc/issues/115) with others also being confused by its scope.

TypeDoc is not the same thing as TSDoc. TSDoc is a doc comment standard that will eventually be adopted by TypeDoc, whereas TypeDoc is a documentation generator. If you give TypeDoc that class (assuming it is exported), then it will properly document it as a class with a property `message` having the provided description.